# Angular 2 cannot call nested json

Tags: angular

In short, if I call

```
{{ foo.bar | json }}
```

Where foo is a json object, and bar is a json object within foo, Angular 2 will load the data in foo.bar fine, and display the json object. If I try foo.bar.baz, it errors with

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in [
{{ foo.bar.baz | json }}
in BarComponent@1:9]
```

How can I pull the data I need from this json?

foo.bar object:

Here's the contents of foo.bar:

```
{ "displayName": null,
"facebookUrl": null, 
"featureCountry": null, 
"id": "some-uuid", 
"name": "Fake Name", 
"permalink": "fake-name", 
"placeIds": [], 
"redemptionProcesses": [ "PAPER_VOUCHER", "DIGITAL_VOUCHER" ], 
"salesforceAccountId": "sfid123",
"websiteUrl": "http://fake.com"
}
```

Specifically, I'm trying to pull name & websiteUrl.

I also have another similar setup, except it's a json array I'm iterating over with ngFor. That works fine.

Comment: Can you paste in the code/ or object?

Comment: Added json object returned by foo.bar above

Comment: `{{ foo?.bar | json }}`

Comment: Adding the ? doesn't help

Comment: This data is getting returned from an HTTP request?

Comment: Yes. I'm grabbing the response body in json, and trying to drill down to the data I need.

Comment: Thanks Eric. The Elvis operator did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, your template is trying to render the data before the `http.get()` request returns and populates the data.  Use the [Elvis operator, ?.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#expression-operators) (see @Eric's comment), or use `NgIf`:

```
<div *ngIf="yourObject">
     {{yourObject.name}}
</div>
```

`NgFor` likely works because the array is initially empty, which won't generate an error because there's nothing to loop over until the data comes back from the server.

Comment: That was it! I added Elvis operator to both objects (foo & bar) and now it works. bar is added via a query expansion to foo, and I bet that additional query wasn't finished before the template rendered. Thanks a lot Mark and Eric!

Comment: Actually I only need ? on bar, since that's the part that loads after the template renders.